# How do you get the number of items in a document library?

Tags: sharepoint-online

I am trying to figure out the number of files in my document library?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can edit your view and under the section "Folders" select the option "Show all items without folders" this will display the total count of documents incl. files in folders. Keep in mind this does not show your folder structure. THe other option is the select the other option "Show items inside folders" which will give you the count of all items in the library excluding nested folders.

[image: Edit View]

Here is how it will display:

[image: Count]

Comment: Thanks Orlando . This looks good and seems to solve the issue.